# Download file from server location, using send_from_directory and filename

Tags: python, flask, download, upload

I'm struggling to understand how to pass an uploaded filename to the next @app.route in flask to retrieve a file saved on the server.

I have been able to create a form to upload the file to the server like this, and have been able to render the file data and the filename to the proceeding view.

```
@app.route('/file_upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():

form = UploadForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    f=form.file.data
    filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
    file_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)
    f.save(file_path)
    Input_data_dataframe = pd.read_excel(f)
    return render_template('Set_parameters.html',filename=filename,tables=[Input_data_dataframe.to_html(classes=["table table-dark table-hover"], header="true", index=False,)])

return render_template('file_upload.html',form=form)
```

The file successfully saves at the required server destination, and the filename is also rendered in the next view like so:

[image: Filename is transferred to view]

I now want this file to be retrieved from the server location for further processing. I understand that I can use the send_from_directory() function to retrieve the file, however I am not sure how to implement it with the correct filename from the previous @app.route('/file_upload')

```
@app.route('/Set_Parameters/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def processing(filename):

retrievedfile= send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename=filename, as_attachment=False)
Input_data_dataframe = pd.read_excel(retrievedfile) #converts uploaded file to a dataframe astype(int)

if request.method == 'POST':

    Input_value1= request.form.get['Input_value1'] #get html form data value
    Input_value= request.form.get['Input_value2'] #get html form data value

    return render_template('Results.html',Input_value1=Input_value1, Input_value2=Input_value2, tables=[Input_data_dataframe.to_html(classes=["table table-dark table-hover"], header="true", index=False,)])
return render_template('Set_parameters.html')
```

Currently if I was to run as is, I would get this error
**TypeError: processing() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'** as I can understand I haven't passed the filename to the function.. I am just unsure how to do this without hardcoding the filename into the code, and then to use the same file for further processing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `processing` function expects `filename` parameter from URL. You can see how it should be done here: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules.

Route to this view should be: `/Set_Parameters/<filename>/`. It means that `action` attribute of the from should be, for example: `action="/Set_Parameters/This_is_the_file.xlsx"`. 
If you render that form in flask, using flask templates, it should be easy if you have a filename in a render context:

```
<form action="/Set_Parameters/{{ filename }}">
...
</form>
```

Comment: Great thanks Michal S. I was able to solve that issue! I can pass the filename and retrieve the file from the server.. I'm not just having an issue putting that file back into a pandas dataframe.. I get the following error:

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'flask.wrappers.Response'>

Comment: `send_from_directory` creates a Response object ready to be returned by the view (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory). To open a file, you can probably just use regular `open(file_path)` function. File path should be `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + filename`, but I'm not sure